# Changing widget assets path at runtime

Tags: php, yii2

I have a widget that uses assets. The asset look like this:

```
class publicHeaderNavbarAsset extends AssetBundle {
    public $sourcePath = '@app/components/@device';
    public $css = [
        'styles.css'
    ];
    public $js = [];
    public $depends = [];
}
```

I also have a (bootstrapped) component, defined like that:

```
class Aliases extends Component {
    public function init() {
        Yii::setAlias('@device', Utils::device());
    }
}
```

`Utils::device()` is a function that parses the UA of the device and returns `mobile`, `tablet` or `desktop`, depending on the device type.

The problem is that Yii2 doesn't seem to be converting `@device` to the value it has. I first thought that it could be my fault, but then I changed the `sourcePath` to:

```
public $sourcePath = '@app/components/@app';
```

just to see if that will trigger an error with a duplicated path  (`basepath/componenets/basepath`), but it didn't.

Is there a way I can change the `sourcePath` of my asset at runtime? Or maybe make Yii2 parse all the aliases in `sourcePath`?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the getAlias function http://www.getyii.com/doc-2.0/api/yii-baseyii.html#getAlias()-detail
It will basically not match your second alias in the string you have given it.

You can try setting

```
Yii::setAlias('@device', '@app/components/' . Utils::device());
```

and

```
public $sourcePath = '@device';
```

This should work as you should be able to set an alias based on another alias
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-aliases.html#defining-aliases